# How to make EditorX design responsive?

Tags: flexbox

I made a website in EditorX. In the editor, I configured it to display correctly for all default device sizes. While everything looks fine in the editor, when you log in from your smartphone, you can see a successful non-adaptive interface, which I have absolutely no idea what caused it. I will attach screenshots. I really don't understand what I did wrong. Previously, I worked mostly only with the Editor, and there were no such problems. I didn't find any solution anywhere in the references either.

Here is the link to the site: https://officeimage.editorx.io/hanszimmer

This is how the site looks in the editor for all devices:
[image]
[image]
[image]

And this is what it looks like on the phone:[image]

I have tried a lot. The settings for my mood elements are set to Flexible, but that still doesn't solve the problem of responsiveness.

Comment: Please note https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761 - your deadlines aren't relevant to SO.

Comment: okay I am sorry